# Generate dropdown with scaffolding in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

i am new in mvc and just reading a article from this link http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/ef-code-first-and-data-scaffolding-with-the-asp-net-mvc-3-tools-update

view the below image there is two model class one is product and one is category and category class has one property called Products which return ICollection

and when generate UI with scaffolding pointing to product model class then UI generate with product details and a dropdown appear for category.

i just do not understand how scaffolding incorporate a drodown for category when generate a UI page for product. product has no link for category but how category related drodown comes in product page. just help me to understand it. thanks

here are few screen shot
[image]
[image]

[image]

i just like to know when we generate product view page using scaffolding then we point our product model class and product model class has no property for category then why and how category related drop down appear in product view page. if u know the reason then share the concept in detail. thanks

Comment: `Product` does have a relationship with `Category` - it contains propertyies `public virtual Category Category { get; set; }` and `public int `CategoryId { get; set; }` (which matches the name of a property in `Category`) so the scaffolding code can identify that relationship and render the appropriate select control.

Comment: @StephenMuecke : thanks for answer. why category class has a property called Products which return ICollection<Product> ? any how is it related with category dropdown?
if i remove this property then scaffolding will generate category drodown ?